# What is the name of this particular algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

The algebra considers of 3 bases: **i, h, l** that have the following properties:

$ i^{2} = h^{2} = -1
 \\ l^{2}=+1 $

[image]

The above image is the Cayley table of the basis elements.
So any element p of this algebra is of the form:
$ p = a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{h}+d\mathbf{l} \ (\forall (a,b,c,d) \in\mathbb{R} $ and like the quaternions each p has its conjugate
$ \overline{p} = a -b\mathbf{i}-c\mathbf{h}-d\mathbf{l} \ $  
Such that the product of p and its conjugate gives 
$p\cdot \overline{p} = (a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{h}+d\mathbf{l})(a-b\mathbf{i}-c\mathbf{h}-d\mathbf{l})= a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}$ 
So it is like the quaternions in terms of being non-commutative but it is non associative and has zero divisors. But does it have an official name?

Comment: Where did this algebra come from, if I might ask?

Comment: Looks like there is a simplectic structure behind ?

Comment: @BrianTung I actually came up with it by myself when it occurred to me to try to construct an algebra based on the quaternions but with 2 real bases and 2 complex bases. The name I thought of for it was: pseudoquaternions. But I wondered if was discovered by others before me and surely it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algebra is called a *Lie-admissible algebra*. In fact,
$$
[x,y]=x\cdot y-y\cdot x
$$
defines a $4$-dimensional Lie algebra $L$. Denote the basis $\{1,i,h,l\}$ by $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$, then the (nonzero) Lie brackets are defined by
$$
[e_2,e_3]=2e_4,\;[e_2,e_4]=-2e_3,\;[e_3,e_4]=2e_2. 
$$
Over the complex numbers, this Lie algebra is isomorphic to
$$
L\cong \Bbb C\oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C).
$$